# When mouse over I want to bring background image to whole div

Tags: html, css

Having issue in my background image when I mouse over to particular div, I want to bring a image, When I a:hover to p1 div.How do I do this? but The image should be in p1 div via, because I need to give anchor tag.

```
 .product
    {
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    }

    .p1
    {
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#333333;
    }

    .p1 a
    {
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
    }

   .p1 a:hover
    {
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background-image:url(../img/dynamic/girlsproduct-01.png);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML as well?  What do you mean by "*bring a image*'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a layer in the div without :hover. Example:

```
.p1  {
background-image: url('transparency.png');
}

.p1  {
background-image: url('theimage.png');
}
```

It is not common to apply ':hover' to change background. It doesn't seem semantic.But when you use two different values for the same attribute it becomes worse.

You can use JavaScript, maybe JQuery, with a code similar to this:

```
function() {
   $('#p1').hover(function(){
     $('#p1').css('background-image','url(image.png)');
     });
 });
```